# Get IE version on Delphi - registry solution not working

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, registry

I use this function to get IE version. But in some cases it cannot find this key and returns 0. Is there another way that does not rely on registry ?

```
function GetIEVersion: string;
var
   Reg: TRegistry;
   S: string;
   i : integer;
begin
   Reg := TRegistry.Create;
   with Reg do
      begin
         RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
         OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer', False);
         if ValueExists('Version') then
          begin
            S := ReadString('Version');
          end
         else
         begin
            S := '0';
         CloseKey;
        end;
         Free;
      end;
    result := s;
end;
```

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I would think that there should be a way to check all installed software (also using registry), and perhaps a way to recognize the version that way. Or, if you can locate the application `iexplore.exe`, then you can get the file version from the EXE.

Comment: You can use [`something like this`](http://www.splashsoft.de/Delphi-Artikel/Using-DllGetVersion-to-Determine-the-Version-Number.html) and ask for `shdocvw.dll` library.

Comment: @TLama: that only gets the version of the DLL itself, not the version of IE (iexplore.exe).

Comment: @Remy, then [`this article`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1583/Determine-the-version-of-Internet-Explorer-install) is wrong (or maybe just outdated).

Comment: @TLama: No, it is not wrong. It just covers a lot more possibilities then the OP's code is accounting for.  For example: "Also, do take note that the version number of [shdocvw.dll] is not the same as that stored in the registry. (Although the later versions are starting to have the same numbers.) A table listing the version numbers of the Shdocvw.dll file and the corresponding versions of Internet Explorer may be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1583/Determine-the-version-of-Internet-Explorer-install#shdocvwfull)."

Answer (score 7):

`TRegistry.OpenKey()` uses the `TRegistry.Access` property to know what permissions to request when opening the key.  By default, `TRegistry.Access` is set to `KEY_ALL_ACCESS`, which is restricted to adminstrators only.  Use `TRegistry.OpenKeyReadOnly()` instead.  Also, for good measure, you can get rid of the `ValueExists()` check, as `ReadString()` returns a blank string if the value does not exist.

Try this:

```
function GetIEVersion: string; 
var 
  Reg: TRegistry; 
begin 
  Result := '';
  Reg := TRegistry.Create; 
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE; 
    if Reg.OpenKeyReadOnly('Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer') then
    try
      Result := Reg.ReadString('Version'); 
    finally
      Reg.CloseKey; 
    end; 
  finally
    Reg.Free; 
  end;
  if Result = '' then
    Result := '0'; 
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, will test on customer's machine :)

Comment: +1. I also use `TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ)` to be safe. BTW, is the `Reg.CloseKey` really needed? (`CloseKey` is called when `TRegistry` is destroyed)

Comment: `OpenKeyReadOnly()` does not use the starting value of the `Access` property. It attempts several different combinations (`KEY_READ`, then `STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ or KEY_QUERY_VALUE or KEY_ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS`, then `KEY_QUERY_VALUE`). If successful, it updates the `Access` property with the new value that actually succeeded. `OpenKey()`, on the other hand, does not do that. It uses `Access` as-is and will either succeed or fail.

Comment: `CloseKey()` is not strictly needed, since `Destroy()` will call it, but it is good practice to always explicitally close whatever you explicitally open.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the method of getting a file version information. First we'd get `iexplore.exe` path.

```
function GetIEPath: string;
var
  Reg: TRegistry;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';
  Reg := TRegistry.Create;

  with Reg do
  begin
    try
      RootKey := HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
      OpenKeyReadOnly('CLSID\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}\LocalServer32');
      try
        Result := ReadString('');
      finally
        CloseKey;
        Len := Length(Result);

        if Len >= 2 then
        begin
          if(Result[Len] = '"') then
            Delete(Result, Len, 1);

          if(Result[1] = '"') then
            Delete(Result, 1, 1);
        end
        else
        begin
          Result := '';
        end;
      end;
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

`{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}` is the CLSID for Internet Explorer.
The default key value for `LocalServer32` is `iexplore.exe` path.

Then, we use some API calls, as demonstrated by Simon Grossenbacher, on [this link](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=27), to get a file version info. Modifying his function, we get to this:

```
function GetIEVersion: string;
var
  IEPath: string;
  VerInfoSize: DWORD;
  VerInfo: Pointer;
  VerValueSize: DWORD;
  VerValue: PVSFixedFileInfo;
  Dummy: DWORD;
begin
  Result := '0';

  IEPath := GetIEPath;
  if IEPath = '' then
    Exit;

  VerInfoSize := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(IEPath), Dummy);
  if VerInfoSize = 0 then
    Exit;

  GetMem(VerInfo, VerInfoSize);
  GetFileVersionInfo(PChar(IEPath), 0, VerInfoSize, VerInfo);
  VerQueryValue(VerInfo, '\', Pointer(VerValue), VerValueSize);

  with VerValue^ do
  begin
    Result := IntToStr(dwFileVersionMS shr 16);
    Result := Result + '.' + IntToStr(dwFileVersionMS and $FFFF);
    Result := Result + '.' + IntToStr(dwFileVersionLS shr 16);
    Result := Result + '.' + IntToStr(dwFileVersionLS and $FFFF);
  end;
  FreeMem(VerInfo, VerInfoSize);
end;
```

Then, you just use, for example, this:

```
ShowMessage(GetIEVersion);
```

Comment: Thanks, will test on customer's machine :)

Comment: `if (Result[1] = '"') then` will raise an AV  if `Result` is empty string (that said, I upvoted this answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
function TFuncoesSO.GetIEVersion(AOnlyMajorVersion: Boolean = False): string;
var
   lVersao: string;
   lReg: TRegistry;
begin
   Result := '';

   lReg := TRegistry.Create;

   try

      lReg.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

      if lReg.OpenKeyReadOnly('Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer') then
      begin
         lVersao := '';

         if lReg.ValueExists('svcVersion') then
         begin
            lVersao := lReg.ReadString('svcVersion');
         end
         else if lReg.ValueExists('Version') then
         begin
            lVersao := lReg.ReadString('Version');
         end
         else if lReg.ValueExists('IVer') then
         begin
            lVersao := lReg.ReadString('IVer');
         end;

         if (lVersao <> '') then
         begin
            if (AOnlyMajorVersion) then
            begin
               if (WordCount(lVersao, ['.']) > 0) then
               begin
                  lVersao := ExtractWord(1, lVersao, ['.']);
               end;
            end;
         end;

         Result := lVersao;

         lReg.CloseKey;
      end;

   finally
      lReg.Free;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please explain your answer a bit or comment in your code.